# Show HTTP link in Kotlin deprecated annotation message

Tags: kotlin, annotations, deprecated

How to have a labelled HTTP link inside the @Deprecated Kotlin annotation?

```
@Deprecated("Use [the new approach](https://my.example.com) instead.")
```

This shows as a normal text in the IDE suggestion window.

How to show it as a hyperlink that would take the developer to the URL in the browser on click from the IDE suggestion window?